# Rails Dependent Form - Selecting a Specific Item from a Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm new to Rails so be gentle. I've got a model, 'Event', with the the following information: 'sport', 'home_team', 'away_team', and 'time' in datetime.

Now I want to enable the user to 'follow' a specific event and am trying to find the best way to do so. Ideally, I'd like a form with dependent drop down lists. For example, the user first picks a 'day', then a 'sport', then selects from a relevant list of 'events' of that 'day' and 'sport'. This association is then stored in a rich join table called 'following'.

I've seen tutorials on complex forms that involve multiple models, but what about when everything is from the same model? How do build a form to grab a handful of relevant records. I only have a few distinct values for 'sport', so I wasn't sure it made sense to give it its own model. And can I easily get events on a certain date from a 'datetime' value?

Answer (score 0):

There a lot of ways to go about this,  here is one option:
Since you want to see multiple events,  you'd probably start off focused on the index action.  Start off by creating and index action,  but add some hooks to filter it,  i.e.

```
def index
  if params[:sport]
    @events = Event.where("sport = ?",params[:sport])
  else
    @events = Event.all()
  end
end
```

Now, if you've defined your routes like this:

resources :events

You'll have a a route /events that will accept a get request and route you to the index action.

But if you want a form where you can select things,  a form will by default POST,  but you could create a form that GETs to '/events'

i.e. in app/views/events/index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag '/events', :method=>:get  %>
```

Then,  you want to create your form elements that will send the params.

i.e.

```
<%= select_tag 'sport', '<option>baseball</option><option>football</option>' %>
```

Put in a submit button

```
<%= submit_tag 'See Events'
```

Then 'end' your form with

```
<% end %>
```

Now when you click on the 'See Events'  button,  you will send a get request to the route  '/events',  and the 'sport' parameter will show up in the index action,  filtering the events.

To keep things simple and all in the index view,  after your form you'd list all the events.

```
<% @events.each do |e| %>
  Sport: <%= e.sport %><br/>
  Home Team: <%= e.home_team %><br/>
  Away Team: <%= e.away_team %><br/>
  Time: <%= e.time.strftime('%H %M') %><br/>
<% end %>
```